# Flaky tests (maven-surefire-plugin) do not appear on the output (console and report)

Tags: junit, maven-surefire-plugin

I want to use maven-surefire-plugin (version 2.18.1) to rerun failing junit (version 4.12) tests (http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/rerun-failing-tests.html). According to documentation - I set rerunFailingTestsCount property and when test fails, it is executed again, but on the console I get (e.g. first time test failed, second time - passed):

```
Tests run: 2, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 2.299 sec <<< FAILURE! - in sth.sth.ReRunTest
someRerunTest(sth.sth.ReRunTest)  Time elapsed: 1.779 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.AssertionError: expected null, but was:<sth>
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
    at org.junit.Assert.failNotNull(Assert.java:755)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertNull(Assert.java:737)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertNull(Assert.java:747)
    at sth.sth.ReRunTest(ReRunTest.java:14)
```

but it should be:

```
 Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Flakes: 1
```

Should I set anything else in the surefire configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Please, use junit 4.11 and maven-surefire-plugin 2.19. 
I don't know the exact minimum version.

mvn -Dsurefire.rerunFailingTestsCount=2 test
-> Tests run: 12, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 1, Flakes: 2